# elastic beanstalk eb create how to specify an existing loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a network LB that i created from console with a static IP.
I created the environment with eb create and elb type network. I need the static ip address for the environment.

I did a reassign of the listener that 'eb create' created to the manual LB i created on the console.  This worked for static ip requirement.

But when the environment gets rebuild, it fails.

How can i assign this LB when creating an environment using eb create instead of manually doing it?

Comment: You can't assign existing resources to Elastic Beanstalk. EB wants to manage everything and create everything for you. It sounds like maybe you should just be using regular EC2 services directly instead of trying to use EB.

Comment: Is there a way to assign an ip when creating the environment/application  eb create --elbtype network <static ip>